# Python: Split list based on first character of word

Tags: python, list, sorting, split, alphabetical

Im kind of stuck on an issue and Ive gone round and round with it until ive confused myself.

What I am trying to do is take a list of words:

```
['About', 'Absolutely', 'After', 'Aint', 'Alabama', 'AlabamaBill', 'All', 'Also', 'Amos', 'And', 'Anyhow', 'Are', 'As', 'At', 'Aunt', 'Aw', 'Bedlam', 'Behind', 'Besides', 'Biblical', 'Bill', 'Billgone']
```

Then sort them under and alphabetical order:

```
A
About
Absolutely
After

B
Bedlam
Behind
```

etc...

Is there and easy way to do this?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Use [`itertools.groupby()`](http://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) to group your input by a specific key, such as the first letter:

```
from itertools import groupby
from operator import itemgetter

for letter, words in groupby(sorted(somelist), key=itemgetter(0)):
    print letter
    for word in words:
        print word
    print
```

If your list is already sorted, you can omit the `sorted()` call. The `itemgetter(0)` callable will return the first letter of each word (the character at index 0), and `groupby()` will then yield that key plus an iterable that consists only of those items for which the key remains the same. In this case that means looping over `words` gives you all items that start with the same character.

Demo:

```
>>> somelist = ['About', 'Absolutely', 'After', 'Aint', 'Alabama', 'AlabamaBill', 'All', 'Also', 'Amos', 'And', 'Anyhow', 'Are', 'As', 'At', 'Aunt', 'Aw', 'Bedlam', 'Behind', 'Besides', 'Biblical', 'Bill', 'Billgone']
>>> from itertools import groupby
>>> from operator import itemgetter
>>> 
>>> for letter, words in groupby(sorted(somelist), key=itemgetter(0)):
...     print letter
...     for word in words:
...         print word
...     print
... 
A
About
Absolutely
After
Aint
Alabama
AlabamaBill
All
Also
Amos
And
Anyhow
Are
As
At
Aunt
Aw

B
Bedlam
Behind
Besides
Biblical
Bill
Billgone
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of using any library imports, or anything fancy. 
  Here is the logic:

```
def splitLst(x):
    dictionary = dict()
    for word in x:
       f = word[0]
       if f in dictionary.keys():
            dictionary[f].append(word)
       else:
            dictionary[f] = [word]
     return dictionary

splitLst(['About', 'Absolutely', 'After', 'Aint', 'Alabama', 'AlabamaBill', 'All', 'Also', 'Amos', 'And', 'Anyhow', 'Are', 'As', 'At', 'Aunt', 'Aw', 'Bedlam', 'Behind', 'Besides', 'Biblical', 'Bill', 'Billgone'])
```

Answer (score 0):

def split(n):
n2 = []
for i in n:
if i[0] not in n2:
n2.append(i[0])
n2.sort()
for j in n:
z = j[0]
z1 = n2.index(z)
n2.insert(z1+1, j)
return n2

word_list = ['be','have','do','say','get','make','go','know','take','see','come','think',
'look','want','give','use','find','tell','ask','work','seem','feel','leave','call']
print(split(word_list))